# WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: wordpress, plugins, checkout, woocommerce

I'm creating a plugin for WooCommerce to modify the Checkout page.  I would like to do some conditional filters based on the users shopping cart.  Is there a way to look at the items in the shopping cart, and determine if any of the items are NOT downloadable/virtual?

So far I have a filter and in the filter I want to hide the address fields.  This works great, but now I want to make it conditional, and only hide the address fields if a non-downloadable product is included.  Thanks

```
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $hasPhysicalProduct = 0;
    if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( SOMEHOW CHECK IF THE PRODUCT IS DOWNLOADABLE ) {
                $hasPhysicalProduct = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not really a programming question as its asking for suggestions

Comment: Hi Riggs - sorry, I'm new here :)  I added some more information to my post.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what will be the functionality, overall what modifications are you trying to implement, something like this ? https://www.fmeaddons.com/woocommerce-plugins-extensions/additional-checkout-fields.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_product` is an instance of WC_Product, so you should be able to do this:

```
if ( $_product.is_downloadable() ) {
     $hasPhysicalProduct = 1;
}
```

The WooCommerce docs has information about the [WC_Product class members](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)